# How to use DataTables to do table pagination?

Tags: pagination, datatables

I want to apply the DataTables example (http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html) to do table pagination。 But I cannot get what the demo shows.

Any suggestion how to use DataTables?

```
<html>
...

<table id='example'>
...
<table>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#example').dataTable( {
         "sPaginationType": "scrolling"
     } );
 } );
</script>
```

...

Answer (score 1):

I have added this for pagination

```
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
```

Try different pagination type format

https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType

Answer (score 0):

This might do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    } );
} );
</script>
```